# Merge from upstream branch to vendor branch, where vendor branch contains a subset of the upstream commits

Tags: android, git, version-control, merge, branch

I am working with a vendor who provides a patchset to the linux kernel in order to support android on top of their platform. This means that they base their string of patches on a specific linux version, and in their string of patches some of the android patches are included (cherry-picked I assume), which are applied to the same linux version.

So the history looks something like this when imported into git along with our changes which are applied on top:

```
     v2.6.x.y                          v_rel_x.y      o_rel_z
l--l--l---------v--v--a--v--a--a--v--v--v--------o--o--o
```

Where `l` are linux commits, `v` are vendor commits, `a` are android commits, and `o` are our commits.

What makes this complicated is that the android git kernel source based on the same linux kernel version is completely separate, looking like this:

```
     v2.6.x.y      v2.6.x.y+1
l--l--l---------l---l
       \             \           android-2.6.x
        \             a--a--a--a--a
         \
          \                       v_rel_x.y      o_rel_z
           v--v--a--v--a--a--v--v--v--------o--o--o
```

Now, I want to include all of the android patches in the android-2.6.x release, however I also want all the vendors patches to support their platform. Unfortunately quite a few of the changes in the `v2.6.x.y+1..android-2.6.x` changeset are already applied to the `v_rel_x.y` branch. Thus a simple merge from android-2.6.x to o_rel_z creates a huge number of conflicts, which are simply impossible to solve by hand.

**Do you have any idea on how to perform the merge from android-2.6.x to o_rel_z reliably?**

And yes, there are really a huge number of commits on each branch, and the android patches on the v_rel_x.y are completely entangled with the vendor patches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My two cents:

1. The reason of conflict is not that you have some of the commits cherry picked, but because some of the commits are changing the same files in the same places and git cannot apply the diff cleanly.
2. In case of conflicting changes you don't have many choices:
   a) you merge and resolve conflicts to bring the code to the desirable state
   b) you're trying to resolve conflicts automatically by merging using merging strategies like --ours or --theirs depending on what you consider more correct for your purposes.

See here [Git merge documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)

Another approach you may try is to rebase your 0_rel_z branch on top of the updated upstream android-2.6.x

Finally, your problem is not the conflicts them-selves, but the amount of them that you have to deal with at once. So I would take a look at improving the process how you are managing the updates, may be to make this more often (daily vs weekly, for example) and constantly rebasing your development branches on top of the updating upstream until you're ready to finalize the development of a feature.

Hope that helps!